# TTL field for a set of columns in CQL3 - Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

Consider the following Insert statement.

```
    INSERT INTO NerdMovies (movie, director, main_actor, year)
                    VALUES ('Serenity', 'Joss Whedon', 'Nathan Fillion', 2005)
    USING TTL 86400;
```

Does the TTL field specify the time to live for the whole set of columns for a particular primary key or just one particular column. Because i would want to specify a TTL for a whole set of columns that should get deleted after the TTL expires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out my self. It sets the TTL for the whole set of columns. so, all the columns for a particular primary key will be deleted once the TTL expires.

Answer (score 3):

@sayed-jalil
To be more precise, it will set TTL for the columns that you mentioned in the INSERT/UPDATE statement. 
So for instance, if at time `t` you do

```
    INSERT INTO NerdMovies (movie, director, main_actor, year)
    VALUES ('Serenity', 'Joss Whedon', 'Nathan Fillion', 2005)
    USING TTL 86400;
```

if you then do the following at time `t + 10`

```
    UPDATE USING TTL 86400 NerdMovies SET year = 2004;
```

then columns `movie`, `director`, `main_actor` will have TTL of `t+86400` and column `year` will have TTL of `t+10+86400`

Hope that makes sense.